# Scrapy Link Extractors does not support base tag

Tags: python, scrapy

If there is a [base](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag in HTML , the relative links are rendered differently. We expected [Link Extractors class](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) in scrapy to handle it automatically. But seems that is not happening.

What would be the standard scrapy way to solve this issue ?

Comment: have you tried the `tags` init argument in the `LinkExtractor` class?

Comment: @Wilfredo- I tried and it worked. Seems the issue is different , its only taking first 4096 characters in HTML to check for base tag. And in our case , its much below it ? Any thoughts on the same

Comment: Found the issue - https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably try the following:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.response import _baseurl_cache
from w3lib import html


def set_base_url(response, base_tag_search_length):
    if response not in _baseurl_cache:
        text = response.text[0:base_tag_search_length]
        _baseurl_cache[response] = html.get_base_url(text, response.url,
                                                     response.encoding)


class CustomLinkExtractor(LxmlLinkExtractor):
    some_other_arbitrary_length = 4096*4

    def extract_links(self, response):
        set_base_url(response, self.some_other_arbitrary_length)
        return super(CustomLinkExtractor, self).extract_links(response)
```

Note: untested code